# How do I export a model from Google AutoML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I created an AutoML model and trained it. I'm interested on downloading the model but I cant figure out how, I tried following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/export-edge) but when I go to the "test and use" tab I don't see the options of TF Lite like are shown in the instructions.Has anyone successfully exported a model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate a test in my project but did not encounter the missing TF lite option. I successfully exported the model after training.

Did you by any chance encountered any issues and/or errors during your training?

By the way, I followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/edge-quickstart) which outlined the steps starting from setting up a project up to exporting the model. (of course you can skip the parts you already did, ie. project setup, creation of GCS bucket).

Alternatively, you can use the ["Container" export](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/export-edge#container) option to export your model in SavedModel format. The saved model format contains the complete tensorflow model. It contains the weights and the information needed to be shared and deployed, as well as for fine-tuning and perform explainability analysis.

Comment: Looking through the tutorial made me realize my error, I had chosen "cloud hosted" when training the model so the option to download was not there, had to re-train and now the option appeared

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to train your modal select, Edge and not cloud hosted. This will allow you to export your modal and cloud hosting is costly if you are going to use the cloud vision for personal projects.